# Node.js spawn process how can i use each line of stdout seperatley to use in functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn

okay so i have my nodejs script below

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var bin = "casperjs";
var args = ['Backend.js'];
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(process.env.PORT);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("socket connection incoming");
});

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
child = spawn(bin, args);
child.stdin.setEncoding = 'utf-8';

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    when (data = "Well Hello1") {
        console.log("Working1");
    }
    if (data = "Well Hello2") {
        console.log("Working2");
    }
    if (data = "Well Hello.") {
        console.log("Working");
    }
});
```

The problems is my if statements are not handled correctly.

I have figured out i need to handle the stdout line by line and not as a stream can any one show me a solution please

Comment: Your comparisons are wrong.  I assume you want `if (data == 'Well Hello.')` or `===`.

Comment: '=' is working fine i want a way o changing the text tream so i can read it line by line also '==' doesnt seem to work i was already trying to use that

Answer (score 0):

You might find that using the `event-stream` module makes this much easier.

You can then do something like this:

```
var es = require('event-stream');

es.pipeline(
    child.stdout,
    es.split(),
    es.map(function (line) {
        if (line === 'Well Hello1') {
            console.log("Working1");
        }
    })
);
```

You'll need to `npm install event-stream` first.

Here's a new version of your full script:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var bin = "casperjs";
var args = ['Backend.js'];
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(process.env.PORT);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("socket connection incoming");
});

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
child = spawn(bin, args);
child.stdin.setEncoding = 'utf-8';

var es = require('event-stream');

es.pipeline(
    child.stdout,
    es.split(),
    es.map(function (line) {
        if (line === 'Well Hello1') {
            console.log("Working1");
        }
    })
);
```

**EDIT**: A simple a script that demonstrates spawning `/bin/cat`, setting up a pipeline to split and then log what is written line-by-line, and sometimes write back to `child.stdin`.  If you run this script it will hang waiting for input to `cat`, but you will see what is output and you can play with it easily:

```
var es = require('event-stream');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var child = spawn('/bin/cat');
var count = 0;

var stream = es.pipeline(
    child.stdout,
    es.split(),
    es.map(function (line) {
        console.log("es.map(" + line + "):");
        if (count < 3) {
            child.stdin.write("Hello(" + count + ")\n");
        }
        count++;
    })
);

child.stdin.write("Testing1\nTesting2");
child.stdin.write("Testing3\nTesting4\n");
child.stdin.write("Testing5\nTesting6\n");

stream.on('data', function (line) {
    console.log(line);
    if (line === '') {
        console.log('end');
        stream.end();
    }
});
```

Comment: will this work along side spawn as i am using spawn for other specefi reasons

Comment: if you could just show me an example updte uing my scripts

Comment: You'll still need to use the rest of your code - I'm just replacing the last bit where you add handlers to `child.stdout`.

Comment: perfect only problem is how do i issues child.stdin.write within the if statments i tried child.stdin.write("in"); but it does not work

Comment: It is no problem to write back to `child.stdin`.  You haven't explained what you are trying to do, so I've no idea what could be going wrong.  I have added a script that you can play with to try to understand things better, without the complexity of interacting with casperjs.  Have a look at the new edit at the end of my answer above.

Comment: FYI, I would suggest asking a *new* question if you are having trouble with something else. It seems this question has been answered successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler example, for ping:

```
var split = require('split');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var child = spawn('ping', ['www.google.com']);

child.stdout.pipe(split()).on('data', function (line) {
    console.log('**' + line + '**');
});
```